# PHP executing sequential commands with windows command line

Tags: php, node.js, windows-8

Can PHP execute sequential commands on windows command line?

For instance, say I wanted to change the directory and then run a .exe file.

I've been trying to do this using exec() and shell_exec() with two separate calls.   Maybe I should be trying to run both commands in the same function call?

I'm using Windows 8 Pro (in Administrator mode).  PHP 5.2.5 -- part of a WAMP install.

I've been trying various permutations (with quotes, double quotes, double back slashes, etc) of:

```
$sExec='c:\Program Files\TileMill-v0.10.2-pre\tilemill  node index.js export white_block ~\Documents\MapBox\export\white_block_13_'.$iI.'.mbtiles --minzoom=13 --maxzoom=13' 
exec ($sExec);
```

EDIT: Maybe this is a problem with using PHP exec() and windows 8 to run Node?

Comment: why the change directory. can't you call the .exe with the full path ? `exec('C:\DOS\RUN\run.exe')`

Comment: It might be a permissions or syntax issue, but I'm unable to get my command line executable to run properly with that method. I'm trying to run TileMill export.

Comment: how about posting the exact code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [chdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) command to change to the directory you wish to run the exe from.

Alternately, consider making a batch file that `cd`s to the correct directory and runs it, then use PHP to run that .bat file.  You'll probably have more luck executing sequential commands that way.

Comment: This is a decent idea.  I forgot to mention that part of the second command is variable (I'm exporting to a different file name each time) - so this means I'd need to rewrite the bat file before each call.  I'd prefer a simpler/faster solution.

Comment: Or have the batch file take parameters?  Then you could pass it the file name you want to work with.

Comment: I created the following bat file: cd \Program Files\TileMill-v0.10.2-pre\tilemill
node index.js export black_block f:\mbtile\black_block_13_xt.mbtiles --minzoom=13 --maxzoom=13

When I run the generate.bat file at the command line it works.  But when I call it using php with exec("generate.bat");  It returns "mbtiles" and doesn't work.

Comment: What is the best way to get php to run a .bat file?

Comment: I can run the bat file.  But the problem is that when I run it in PHP it acts differently (fails) then when I run it directly in the command line.  It successfully changes directory, but when it tries to export with TileMill it returns a cryptic "mbtiles" message which means nothing to me.

Comment: This might be a TileMill problem. I posted in their discussion forum.